# Why does code can not be build when source location is changed in Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a problem with building cpp files when I move them out of Makefile folder. Anyone knows why?

Snippet from the makefile:

```
CC = qcc -Vgcc_nto$(PLATFORM)
CXX = qcc -lang-c++ -Vgcc_nto$(PLATFORM)
LD = $(CXX)
DEPS = -Wp,-MMD,$(@:%.o=%.d),-MT,$@
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -ggdb -O0 
DIR_SRC =./
DIR_OBJ =./
SRCS := $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SRCS:$(DIR_SRC)/%.cpp=$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o)

all: hello_world_test 

$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o : $(DIR_SRC)/%.c
     $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) ${CPPFLAGS} ${DEPS} -c $< -o $@

hello_world_test:  hello_world_test.o
     $(CXX) hello_world_test.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBPATH) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

So in this way, everything is fine but when I move sources to one folder back called "test"

```
DIR_SRC =../test
```

it doesnt work anymore with the message:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'hello_world_test.o', needed by 'hello_world_test'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

```
hello_world_test: hello_world_test.o
```

your `hello_world_test` depends on `hello_world_test.o`.  But your rule tells make how to build `$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o` and `hello_world_test.o` doesn't match that pattern.  Pattern matching in targets is simple string matching, it doesn't do pathname simplification.  You should write your prerequisite as:

```
hello_world_test: $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_test.o
```

Note that you have two slashes here: one in `DIR_OBJ` and one after it.  But anyway.

The reason it worked before is that make was using its built-in recipe to build object files, not your recipe; the built-in recipe has the pattern:

```
%.o : %.c
```

which matched your object file.  If you run make with the `-r` option to remove all built-in rules, you would have seen a failure there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I found out that the problem was in the rule, like you said. 
I changed to $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o : $(DIR_SRC)/%.cpp (before it was .c instead of .cpp :) ) and it works now with changing the DIR_SRC.
I didn't observe this since I was able to build from the current directory but realized after your answer about built-in rule.

Another questions:
1) Does this rule:
$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o : $(DIR_SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) ${CPPFLAGS} ${DEPS} -c $< -o $@

says next: do compile all .cpp files and make .o files out of it and put the .o files in DIR_OBJ?

2) Why I cant change DIR_OBJ location to for instance:
DIR_OBJ =../test and then use hello_world_test: $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_test.o to build the executable?

When I do it I get an error:  cannot find hello_world_test.o: No such file or directory.

I see that .o and .d files are created in the directory where DIR_OBJ is defined (either in ./ or in ../test) and then it makes me quite confused why hello_world_test cant fine prerequisite $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_test.o but it only looks in the current folder where the Makefile is.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was the problem:

I haven't added $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_test.o in 
$(CXX) hello_world_test.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBPATH) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

but now still confused, if my understanding is right that $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o : $(DIR_SRC)/%.cpp  will create $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_test.o how come that hello_world_client:  $(DIR_OBJ)/hello_world_client.o couldn't find prerequisite?